# Unable To Get Implicit Objects In WCMPojo

Tags: aem

I am using a component where there is need of dynamic dropdown. The options are configured in the page properties. But I am unable to get currentPage Object in datasource.html file. Below is the structure of my component.

[image]

And datasource calling the wcmpojo class. Below in the flow.

[image]

datasource.html

```
<sly data-sly-use.data="${'apps.myprj.components.content.tabcontent.HtlDatasourceExample'  @ text=currentPage.path}">
</sly>
```

HtlDatasourceExample is getting call and resulting correct response if values are hardcoded.

**Issue is unable to get sling objects in HtlDatasourceExample such as currentPage.**

Thanks

Comment: Is `HtlDatasourceExample` a Sling model or a class extending the `WCMUsePojo`? If it is extending `WCMUsePojo` use the method `getCurrentPage` to get the current page, if it is a sling model, you can inject the current page using `@ScriptVariable`.

Comment: Its WCMPOJO and getCurrentPage is null same issue with other objects as well. When we include any html via slingResourceType then this issue is coming

Comment: you may need to add your java code to the question as well.

Comment: Hi, This snippet done the job.         `String pagePath = getRequest().getRequestPathInfo().getSuffix().replaceAll("/jcr:content/.*$", "");`